# Choosing appropriate data split

Tags: cross-validation

I have a dataset where user's device parameters are given and one has to predict whether the user will perform a particular action (binary classification).

I need some advice on splitting my data into train-test parts. Obviously, the split should be stratified by target variable since there is a huge class imbalance. But then things get a bit tricky for me.

There is a timestamp column and the data is on the range of several months. I didn't notice any temporal patterns when performing EDA (except for day/night and weekday/weekend features) so I suppose that I don't need to take time into account when splitting?

And here's the most tricky part for me. Some users appear several times in the dataset and different entries have different values of the target variable. Should I use group-based splitting and make each user belong to either train or test part?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the users, I'd be on the safe side and split training/test users, yes. 
If that doesn't take too much time, you can do an additional quick check whether results appear to look much better with a split not according to users and thus find out whether your models "learn users".

For the timestamp, day/night and weekday/weekend are features that your model can legitimately learn, and it doesn't sound sensible to ask for a weekday day model's predictive performance on weekend nights. 
You may want to do a sanity check on overall trend/drift and do an additional split that trains on the first n months and then predicts the remaining. Here, it is interesting to check whether prediction accuracy dropy if the predictions are further in the future.